# Deleted item still showing on the Result page. 

Tags: java, android

I'm able to edit or delete single item without any problem but when I click delete button after edit an item, the item is still showing on the ListView even though it has been deleted from the database.

ListViewActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_requests);

    requestsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadAllRequests().execute();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String request_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.request_id)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ViewRequestActivity.class);
            // sending rid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, request_id);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 55);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of closing and reopening the activity, you should use [invalidateViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29)

```
yourListView.invalidateViews();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign the adapter to the listview again

Answer (score 0):

You can also try refreshing the activity. I believe that it is ListViewActivity.restart();